# Comparison of surds

Tags: inequality

Smallest among $\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{3},\ \sqrt{7}-\sqrt{4}, \sqrt{11}-\sqrt{8},\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{7}$. I tried comparing by squaring each term but that doesn't help.

Comment: **Hint**: Try multiplying and dividing by their conjugates. Notice what happens to the numerators.

Comment: $\sqrt{x+3}-\sqrt x$ is a decreasing function

Comment: @KM101 What about denominators ?

Comment: What happens when the denominators increase (while the numerators stay constant)?

Comment: My teacher told to multiply the numbers inside surd in each case. The one with highest product is the smallest term. But what is the logic behind this?

Comment: @KM101 Now I get you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: $$\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n}=\frac{3}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+3}}$$ is a decreasing function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  \frac{3}{\sqrt {11} + \sqrt 8} <   \frac{3}{\sqrt {10} + \sqrt 7} < \frac{3}{\sqrt {7} + \sqrt 4} <   \frac{3}{\sqrt {6} + \sqrt 3} $$